# Jordan Blocks tricks?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any trick, we could easily determine the size of Jordan blocks without calculating the eigenvectors and so on ?

> For example for this matrix we see the algebraic multiplicities of all eigenvalues and we can say that there are total of 3 eigenvectors. But can we say for which eigenvalue how much eigenvectors we have?

[image]

Comment: No trick necessary here. We know already the Jordan blocks. The first one has size $3$, then we have two blocks of size $1$ etc."How much eigenvalues"? Infinitely many. If $Av=\lambda v$, then $tv$ is also an eigenvector for all $t\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Computing the Jordan Form requires computing "Generalized Eigenvectors". The number of them required corresponds to the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces of the matrix, which requires computing eigenvectors of the operator.

Comment: These generalized eigenvectors are used to compute the rest of the Jordan Basis for each Jordan Block.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean to ask instead about the dimensions of the eigenspaces $$E_\lambda = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^9 : Jv = \lambda v\},$$ as opposed to the number of eigenvectors.

Knowing the Jordan form allows us to read off this dimension, as
$$\dim E_\lambda = \text{number of Jordan blocks corresponding to the eigenvalue } \lambda$$
which immediately gives
$$\dim E_4 = 3 \\ \dim E_1 = 2 \\ \dim E_{-2} = 1$$